# Center ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view, android-gravity

I want to full center a progressbar with a full height/width webview, and i'm not able to. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.stevejobs.iphone.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"/>
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I missing any line here to center it? The progressBar appears on te top left corner right now.

Comment: What happens if you delete the three last lines of WebView ?

Comment: @Orionss I tried both too but nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.stevejobs.iphone.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

   <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_centerVertical` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal` are excessive, because `android:layout_centerInParent` covers them both.

Comment: @azizbekian That worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.stevejobs.iphone.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your progressBar outside the webview Do like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.stevejobs.iphone.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```